# Is there a standard name for the card game "kabou"?

Tags: identify-this-game

The game is played with french cards (4 colors: ace, 2 - 10, Jack, Queen, King; jokers). You need at least 2 players, but you can have more. A game of Kabou has arbitrary many rounds. In each round, each player gets an integer amount of points (which might be negative). The less points, the better.

### One round

Each player gets 4 cards (hidden) in front of him. The order may not be switched. There is a order among players in which they get to play their turns. Each turn consists of:

- (a) Drawing a card or (b) taking the top most card of the stack
- If you drew a card, you may either (a) play it (put it open on the stack) or (b) exchange it with one of the cards in front of you.

  - When you exchange it, you put the exchanged card open on the stack.
  - When you play it some effect happens, depending on the card (see below)
- When the card is put on the stack, the turn of one player ends and the next begins.

In every situation, players may put a card they know (from the ones lying in front of all players) on the stack, if the value (ace, 2-10, jack,queen king, joker) is the same. If they put it on the stack from another players cards, they can give that player one of their cards.

When a player thinks he is in a good situation, he can say "Kabou" right before he does anything in his turn. He skips his turn, the game goes on until he would get his turn again. Other players may not exchange cards from him, but besides that the turns are just normal.

### Card effects

- 7, 8: take a look at one of your cards
- 9, 10: take a look at another players cards
- Jack, Queen: Exchange 1 card from another player with 1 of your cards. Don't look at any of them.
- heart king: Take a look at one card of another player. Then decide if you want to exchange that card with one of your cards.

### Card values

higher is worse

- joker: -1
- black king: 0
- Ace: 1
- 2 - 10: Card value (2 - 10)
- Jack: 11
- Queen: 12
- red king: 13

What is the name of this game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Game you are looking for is called "Cabo". Have a look at the Wikipedia description:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabo_%28game%29